# Raspberry Pi2 Windows 10 IOT core and Visual Basic 2015

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, gambas

Is it possible to run Visual Studio on a Raspberry PI 2 with Windows IOT core on it?

I want to creating create a touch-screen (HDMI with RPI2) application on Windows 10, which will be used to take the orders of customers and transfer the order information to another Raspberry PI running MySQL server.

I was able to implement this on PC but I want to implement it on RPI.  Is it possible or should I use Gambas for that purpose?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am working on Official RPi 7" Touchscreen(https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/) for Windows IoT with a community member. This display works with RPi2 + Windwos IoT but touch won't works. We are working to get support for touch and got partial success to retrieve touch data but we still require 1-2 months. Hope that Microsoft will soon release support for Official RPi 7" Touchscreen in Windwos IoT.

Once we got success, will report back here with source code.

> **Update (15-DEC-2015)**
>   Right now, RPi2 (Windows IoT) supports a touchscreen display from [chalkboard electronics](http://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/7-black-frame-universal-HDMI-LCD-with-capacitive-multi-touch/p/21750201/category=3094861) only. Setup instruction for this touchscreen is given at [ms-iot Website's](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm#Miscellaneous) Miscellaneous section.

Comment: Thanks @Anurag I will be looking forward...!!

Comment: As per the Microsoft employee on [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff0e1768-9105-4027-9ca0-6af75e79ed0a/win-10-iot-core-rpi?forum=WindowsIoT), you won't able to use default MySql on Windows IoT because service required for it will need to be compiled for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

you might try to use the driver provided by MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-rt.html

But my suggestion would to create an UWP app for your client Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT Core and a web service to expose your MySQL database server on the other Raspberry Pi running a Linux distribution.
So the key is to make your client consume a web service. This way, you can change your service location or database format freely.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @danvy...... I know we can remotely debug the application from PC using Visual Studio...but is it not possible to initiate the app from Rpi(windows 10 client) itself like an .exe or something or is it that we have to fire the app always from the remote PC with visual studio.

Comment: You can set your app as the default app so it will start as you switch on the device

https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-setting-startup-app-887ed0